# This project needs to migrate WTP metadata error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, metadata, eclipse-wtp

I imported a project and in the problems tab **`This project needs to migrate WTP metadata error in Eclipse`** error appear.  Anyone can explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project having this error and refresh it, problem will be resolved.I think it is about temporary fields but exactly I don't know why it is, if someone explain we can learn.